# Set Image to Fill PyGTK

Tags: python, image, pygtk, glade

I'm using Python 2.7, PyGTK 2.24, and Glade 2.8.0. I'm trying to set an image to (stretch to) fill all of the given space, but I cannot find the properties to do that. Furthermore, I may need to shrink images to fit sometimes as well.

How do I do those two things in Glade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glade does not allow for stretching images. This must be done in code, by scaling the pixbuf, creating a pixmap and mask from it, and then creating the image from the pixmap.